# Passing a Variable from Python script to tcl shell

Tags: python, tcl

I am new to this forum, so I apologize beforehand for any mistakes. I am trying to pass a variable from my python code to tcl script. The way I am doing this is:

```
import os
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

def set_impairments(port,delay):

    port=int(port)
    delay=int(delay)
    tcl = Tcl()
    tcl.eval("""
    proc my_proc {in_port,in_delay} {

    puts in_port
    puts in_delay
    }
    """)
    print port
    print delay

    tcl.eval('my_proc port,delay')

set_impairments(0,25000)
```

The output of this code is:

```
0

25000

in_port

in_delay
```

How to assign in_port to 0 and in_delay to 25000? I am not able to understand why it is not able to pass the value of the variable.

Comment: This is partially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288972/pass-python-variables-to-tkinter-tcl-eval but you can also use the 'eval' + format solution below instead of using a Tkinter StringVar.

Comment: Yeah I have gone through that thread and it didn't help me. Apparently I was missing the point as Glenn suggested to put a $ to reference the value of the variable. Anyway Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl doesn't use commas to separate arguments, it uses whitespace. Also, you need a `$` to reference the value of the variable. Do this:

```
proc my_proc {in_port in_delay} {
    puts $in_port
    puts $in_delay
}
```

I'm not really a python guy, but you probably want

```
tcl.eval('my_proc {0} {1}'.format(port,delay))
```

Comment: One can write the call a bit nicer as `tcl.call('my_proc', port, delay)` which has a bit of magic so you do not need to move through the string rep. Does not work for all python variable types though, but int / string works.

Comment: Thank you so much Glenn.This helped.

Comment: Thank You Schlenk. I will definitely look at it.