# Running tcl script from python with arguments

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I'm trying to run tcl script from python,
tcl script requires command line arguments to execute, when I source the tcl file from python, it then shows the error says

```
tclsh.eval('source "test.tcl"' )
_tkinter.TclError: can't read "::argv": no such variable
```

I've done many searches, majority of them asks how to pass arguments to python in tcl.

python code

```
import tkinter
import sys 
tclsh.eval('source "test.tcl"' )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("hi")
```

tcl code

```
puts [lindex $::argv 0]
```

Is there anyway for me pass python arguments to tcl ?

or

not pass arguments and still compile ?

since if I compile tcl script only without arguments, it still compiles

Note:

In tkinter documentation it says tkinter.Tk is

```
The Tk class is instantiated without arguments
```

Is there a way to instantiated with arguments ?

Sol:

```
tclsh.eval('set argv [list]')
tclsh.eval('set argc 0')
```

I tried to set a global variable and it works for me under python 3.6

Comment: Check if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37875115/1578604)'s answers are of any help?

Comment: @Jerry Hi, I guess no, that question is passing function arguments to tcl function, I;m trying to pass arguments to tcl command line arguments ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global `argv` variable is, apart from being set during the startup of a standard Tcl script, not special in any way. You can therefore just set it prior to doing `source`. In this case, doing so with `lappend` in a loop is probably best as it builds the structure of the variable correctly. There are two other variables that ought to be set as well (`argc` and `argv0`); overall you do it like this (as a convenient function):

```
def run_tcl_script(script_name, *args):
    tclsh.eval('set argv0 {{{}}}'.format(script_name))
    tclsh.eval('set argv {}; set argc 0')
    for a in args:
        tclsh.eval('lappend argv {{{}}}; incr argc'.format(a))
    tclsh.eval('source $argv0')
```

The `{{{}}}` with Python's `str.format` results in a *single* layer of braces being put around the argument, defending against *most* quoting issues.