# _tkinter.TclError: can't find package comm

Tags: python, tcl

Running into this issue when trying to utilize the comm package:

```
>>> interp = tkinter.Tcl()
>>> interp.eval('package require comm')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package comm
```

i'm using python 3.6.8 on windows 10

Comment: Welcome to SO Sblu, could you share the code generating this error please ?

Comment: Assuming it's [this comm package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/comm/comm.md), did you install tcllib?

Comment: @shawn, yes it is that comm package.  i'm new to tcl in general.  how do you check ot see if it is already installed?

Comment: @cbo, the code is posted

Comment: my bad @Sblu, will correct my downvoting accordingly when time limit is passed.

Comment: so I did an offline install of the latest tcllib.  same result

Comment: when I run this outside of python, in tclsh: package require comm works. the question is how do i either tell python to use the offline package i installed or else update the one that it has to include the comm package

Comment: i also tried this with python 3.8.6, same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the directory where the `comm` package is installed (either the directory containing the `pkgIndex.tcl` or the *immediate parent* directory), you should make sure that's on Tcl's `auto_path` before trying to `package require` the package. The function you need to do that is this:

```
def add_library_directory(tcl_context, directory_name):
    tcl_context.eval("lappend auto_path {}".format(
        # This does the trick to make the string substitution fully safe
        tkinter._stringify(directory_name)))

interp = tkinter.Tcl()
# Up to you to actually find the location...
add_library_directory(interp, "/path/to/dir")
interp.eval('package require comm')
```

For details of `tkinter._stringify`, which is massively underdocumented despite being very useful, see this other Stack Overflow question:

- [Pass Python variables to `Tkinter.Tcl().eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288972/pass-python-variables-to-tkinter-tcl-eval)

Comment: Thanks @Donal.  this helped to move along, but not to resolution, unfortunately.  I can jerry-rig it, by moving directories around, but I'd much rather fix the script.  Where is this being searched for exactly? '''>>> interp.eval('package require comm')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    C:/Python36/lib/tcl8.6 C:/lib/tcl8.6 C:/lib/tcl8.6 C:/library C:/library C:/tcl8.6.6/library C:/tcl8.6.6/library'''

Comment: i realize this is somewhat of a different topic addressed here, for now I just cheated by moving directories around to make progress in lieu of a more elegant solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320039/python-tkinter-throwing-tcl-error

Answer (score 0):

Summary of the solution is as @Donal explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/64884895/14656464 and then possibly followed by this next resolution: [Python Tkinter throwing Tcl error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320039/python-tkinter-throwing-tcl-error) by pointing the offline version of tcl lib that contains the comms library to where the python environment expects it.